# thread example, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, g++, thread-safety

I wrote a simple C++ code to find the minimal value of a vector, find below. It compiles both on VC++ and g++, but runs onto a segmentation fault on the latter. I cannot tell apart if my code contains an UB or the g++ contains a bug. Can someone identify any mistake in my code?

The segfault arises at thread::join().

## some debugging info

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004688f7 in std::thread::join() ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) thread
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7c6880 (LWP 24015))]
```

## Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

void find_min(vector<double>& x, double& min_val, int& min_id)
{
    min_id = distance(x.begin(), min_element(x.begin(), x.end()));
    min_val = x[min_id];
}

void find_part_min(vector<double>& x, vector<int>& min_ids, vector<double>& min_vals, int id)
{
    int start_id = (x.size()*id) / min_vals.size();
    int end_id = (x.size()*(id + 1)) / min_vals.size();
    for (int i = start_id; i < end_id; ++i)
    {
        if (x[i] < min_vals[id])
        {
            min_ids[id] = i;
            min_vals[id] = x[i];
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    // define variables
    int Nthreads = 16;
    vector<double> x(256 * 256);
    int min_id = 0;
    double min_val = 0;

    // fill up vector with random content
    mt19937 gen(0);
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
    generate(x.begin(), x.end(), bind(dis,gen));
    
    // find min serial
    find_min(x, min_val, min_id);
    cout << min_id << "\t" << min_val << endl;
    
    // initilaize variables for parallel computing
    vector<double> min_vals(Nthreads, numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    vector<int> min_ids(Nthreads, -1);
    vector<thread> myThreads;

    for (int id = 0; id < Nthreads; ++id) // define each thread
    {
        thread myThread(find_part_min, ref(x), ref(min_ids), ref(min_vals), id);
        myThreads.push_back(move(myThread));
    }
    for (int id = 0; id < Nthreads; ++id)
        myThreads[id].join(); // part-calculations are finished

    // merging the results together
    min_val = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    min_id = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Nthreads; ++i)
    {
        if (min_vals[i] < min_val)
        {
            min_val = min_vals[i];
            min_id = min_ids[i];
        }
    }

    cout << min_id << "\t" << min_val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When diagnosing a segfault, it is useful to get a backtrace and know where the segfault is occuring.

Comment: Running it through valgrind/helgrind didn't show any issues on linux/g++-5.3

Comment: Claiming run time errors from [code that doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19c20c61347e8a2f) sounds weird.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ maybe including <vector> can be a solution

Comment: @DanielTuzes Provide a [MCVE] as required. Otherwise your question is _off-topic_, that simple. It's your fault, not mine.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ [it does compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1220afc965aa027b) with the correct headers of the standard library

Comment: @DanielTuzes Well, fixing the remaining issue and [adding `-pthread`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31402ae37167d049), we're ending up I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ As you can see in my answer, it was due to a g++ bug and not a bug in my code which prevented me to run the program correctly. I was not able to tell apart which one was the case. Cause I tried with 2 g++ versions and I've got the same result, I thought it is not a compiler and linker issue. But it was indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into the Makefile, and `-static` was used without `-whole-archive`, which leads to problem under g++ according https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-05/msg00029.html

It tells that if libstdc++ is configured without `__thread` support and linking against `-lpthread` is static, this can happen due to a libstdc++ bug.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-pthread` as option for every compilation phase with GCC (g++), rather than linking against `-lpthread`.

There's more stuff involved than simple linkage using that flag actually.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also tried -pthread instead of -lpthread, and itself didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I never said that it actually resolves your problem beyond the sample I have posted.